# Complemented subspaces isomorphic to $c_0$ in $\mathcal{B}(E)$

Tags: banach-spaces, fa.functional-analysis

It is well known that neither

1) $c_0$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of $\mathcal{B}(H)$

nor

2) $c_0$ is a quotient of $\mathcal{B}(H)$

for a Hilbert space $H$. Can we replace $H$ above by any Banach space? Reflexive space?

Comment: PhotonicCrystal got what he wanted, so I vote to close to keep this from returning to the front page.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that this is still open, though there are many partial results.  Look up, e.g., papers by Giovanni Emmanuele on MathSciNet.

Answer (score 0):

$c_0$ is a quotient of ${\cal B}(c_0)$, namely for any nonzero 
$x \in c_0$, the evaluation map $T \to T(x)$ maps  ${\cal B}(c_0)$ onto $c_0$.

Comment: More generally, any Banach space $X$ is isomorphic to a complemented subspace of ${\cal B}(X)$.  Namely for any $x_0 \in X$ and $\phi_0 \in X^*$ with $\phi_0(x_0) = 1$, ${\cal B}(X) = A \oplus B$ where
$A = \{T: T(x_0) = 0\}$ and $B = \{x \otimes \phi_0: x \in X\}$. 


Comment: Neat answer. On a tangential point, for $X$ a Hilbert space, reflexive complemented subspaces of $\mathcal{B}(X)$ are isomorphic to Hilbert space(s); I think this was first observed in published form in the early 1990s by Pisier.

Comment: Isn't $A$ of codimension 1 in $\mathcal{B}(X)$?

Comment: PhotonicCrystal, it would seem to not be of codimension 1, however as a left-ideal it should be maximal in $\mathcal{B}(X)$.

Comment: Fairly good answer is given by G. Emmanuele in:
G. Emmanuele, On complemented copies of c0 in spaces of operators II. *Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin.* 35 (1994), 259-261